# How to align buttons on the bottom at the same line?

Tags: html, css, email

I want all the checkout button to be aligned evenly. Description of different products could be on 2 or 3 lines. And I want these button to stay on the same line. I tried to change line-height, but this affects all the buttons.
Here is a playground for that

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650"><tbody><tr><td>
                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="430"><tbody><tr><td>
                            <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210"><tbody><tr><td>
                                    <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNyNjUtYi1yb3NlLWdvbGQuaHRtbA==" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNyNjUtYi1yb3NlLWdvbGQuaHRtbA%3D%3D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHiQ7uePUKn7qMoF5xqlvjDP1zgyQ"><img class="CToWUd" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/1GKwB3DZSd0BPMDboD6iz7Ouq-wX00lP_G9TEUtJvjk3Gl5217FB6-q7E4qkCVjd5MVbYac2bUu9s5KrC8CNvpOQujvl5A-VraYMFfE8UzcBuw0O_MfbMdTOJhTWu9Rl5oVzd-4fVw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.venusbymariatash.com/media/catalog/product/C/R/CR65_B-ROSE_GOLD_1.png" alt="" style="display:block" border="0" width="210"></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#363636;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;text-align:center;padding:0 0 15px">
                                    1/4" Plain Ring (Earlobe) - ROSE GOLD
                                </td>
                            </tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#363636;line-height:16px;text-align:center">
                                    $110.00
                                </td>
                            </tr><tr><td style="padding:20px 0 0">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px" align="center" bgcolor="#fff">
                                            <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNyNjUtYi1yb3NlLWdvbGQuaHRtbA==" title="CHECKOUT" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px 50px;background-color:rgb(89,89,89);border-radius:5px" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNyNjUtYi1yb3NlLWdvbGQuaHRtbA%3D%3D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHiQ7uePUKn7qMoF5xqlvjDP1zgyQ"><strong>CHECKOUT</strong></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr></tbody></table></td>
                            </tr></tbody></table><table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210"><tbody><tr><td>
                                    <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtd2hpdGUtZ29sZC1jcjY1LWItd2hpdGUtZ29sZC5odG1s" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtd2hpdGUtZ29sZC1jcjY1LWItd2hpdGUtZ29sZC5odG1s&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFtmdKjjV2n6xrI45EjJ6H9WBAXtA"><img class="CToWUd" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/CL7UjYFnWe3FNZINIJJgPOVH18yP9nKSJZJdbbalv96XbhdRdiLweSYJ6DspRUu8KHjFGT9GCjVmgxAQY3Kpa7_aU5yUeMbdAha6dPGV4JVu16m2xSLjMgC3FA8qrs38xyWr1ygiyM0=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.venusbymariatash.com/media/catalog/product/C/R/CR65_B-WHITE_GOLD_1.png" alt="" style="display:block" border="0" width="210"></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#363636;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;text-align:center;padding:0 0 15px">
                                    1/4" Plain Ring (Earlobe) - WHITE GOLD
                                </td>
                            </tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#363636;line-height:16px;text-align:center">
                                    $110.00
                                </td>
                            </tr><tr><td style="padding:20px 0 0; min-height: 100px;">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px" align="center" bgcolor="#fff">
                                            <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtd2hpdGUtZ29sZC1jcjY1LWItd2hpdGUtZ29sZC5odG1s" title="CHECKOUT" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px 50px;background-color:rgb(89,89,89);border-radius:5px" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtd2hpdGUtZ29sZC1jcjY1LWItd2hpdGUtZ29sZC5odG1s&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFtmdKjjV2n6xrI45EjJ6H9WBAXtA"><strong>CHECKOUT</strong></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr></tbody></table></td>
                            </tr></tbody></table></td>
                    </tr></tbody></table><table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210"><tbody><tr><td>
                            <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkY1MTYtZGlhbW9uZC1jb250aW51b3VzLWV0ZXJuaXR5LXJpbmctaGVsaXgtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNldDhkMjItcm9zZS1nb2xkLmh0bWw=" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkY1MTYtZGlhbW9uZC1jb250aW51b3VzLWV0ZXJuaXR5LXJpbmctaGVsaXgtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNldDhkMjItcm9zZS1nb2xkLmh0bWw%3D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGemmOPzKqjaMtL6JMsZ5o-WOOWLw"><img class="CToWUd" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/oXpSdsWCQF_bW7AslUS7Fi71WwkcWjSpNklnWUJtDDgaxexkpoqVKaeIWTopPL8YfTZMqfOBV-jW7SV3DOGMi5Eq-o8FhU9JWH69-f-Ukh4dbVTeFoq9yCIuWWGmSwEOA6eaBgkxhzA=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.venusbymariatash.com/media/catalog/product/C/E/CET8D22-ROSE_GOLD_1.png" alt="" style="display:block" border="0" width="210"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#363636;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;text-align:center;padding:0 0 15px">
                            5/16" Diamond Continuous Eternity Ring (Helix) - ROSE GOLD
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#363636;line-height:30px;text-align:center">
                            $515.00
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr><td style="padding:20px 0 0">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px" align="center" bgcolor="#fff">
                                    <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkY1MTYtZGlhbW9uZC1jb250aW51b3VzLWV0ZXJuaXR5LXJpbmctaGVsaXgtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNldDhkMjItcm9zZS1nb2xkLmh0bWw=" title="CHECKOUT" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px 50px;background-color:rgb(89,89,89);border-radius:5px" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkY1MTYtZGlhbW9uZC1jb250aW51b3VzLWV0ZXJuaXR5LXJpbmctaGVsaXgtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNldDhkMjItcm9zZS1nb2xkLmh0bWw%3D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609005000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFsZwpDCF5k_yDAE66iSd1Sx1ObnQ"><strong>CHECKOUT</strong></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr><tr><td height="15">
                                </td>
                            </tr></tbody></table></td>
                    </tr></tbody></table></td>
            </tr></tbody></table>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGpzVa

Thank you!

Comment: Are you building an HTML email? If not, then your HTML's table structure is disgusting - HTML pages (with the exception of emails) should contain head, body and div tags to build the main structure (a table based structure is extremely deprecated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying a fixed height to the td containing the item titles (if the line-height is 16px, and you want to give 3 lines of space, set a height of 48px);

```
<td style="height:48px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#363636;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;text-align:center;padding:0 0 15px">
    1/4" Plain Ring (Earlobe) - ROSE GOLD
</td>
```

You may have to remove padding.

Failing these, you could pull out the buttons as a whole other row (so long as each column was the same width as the column in the table above so everything lined up)

Comment: Thank you Mattew!! That helps!

Comment: No problem - also, I noticed the lineheight of the $515 is larger than the line height of the other prices - set them all to 16px

Comment: @averty Using HTML in email is very unpredictable, and be aware of that `line-height` need a special set up to work properly in some Outlook versions, therefore better to use separate rows as I suggested in my answer .. I would say, stay away of as many inline styles as you possibly can, and use the old attribute way to style table elements

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to move the buttons to their own row.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="430">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNyNjUtYi1yb3NlLWdvbGQuaHRtbA==" target="_blank"
                        data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNyNjUtYi1yb3NlLWdvbGQuaHRtbA%3D%3D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHiQ7uePUKn7qMoF5xqlvjDP1zgyQ"><img class="CToWUd" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/1GKwB3DZSd0BPMDboD6iz7Ouq-wX00lP_G9TEUtJvjk3Gl5217FB6-q7E4qkCVjd5MVbYac2bUu9s5KrC8CNvpOQujvl5A-VraYMFfE8UzcBuw0O_MfbMdTOJhTWu9Rl5oVzd-4fVw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.venusbymariatash.com/media/catalog/product/C/R/CR65_B-ROSE_GOLD_1.png"
                          alt="" style="display:block" border="0" width="210"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#363636;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;text-align:center;padding:0 0 15px">
                        1/4" Plain Ring (Earlobe) - ROSE GOLD
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#363636;line-height:16px;text-align:center">
                        $110.00
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtd2hpdGUtZ29sZC1jcjY1LWItd2hpdGUtZ29sZC5odG1s" target="_blank"
                        data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtd2hpdGUtZ29sZC1jcjY1LWItd2hpdGUtZ29sZC5odG1s&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFtmdKjjV2n6xrI45EjJ6H9WBAXtA"><img class="CToWUd" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/CL7UjYFnWe3FNZINIJJgPOVH18yP9nKSJZJdbbalv96XbhdRdiLweSYJ6DspRUu8KHjFGT9GCjVmgxAQY3Kpa7_aU5yUeMbdAha6dPGV4JVu16m2xSLjMgC3FA8qrs38xyWr1ygiyM0=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.venusbymariatash.com/media/catalog/product/C/R/CR65_B-WHITE_GOLD_1.png"
                          alt="" style="display:block" border="0" width="210"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#363636;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;text-align:center;padding:0 0 15px">
                        1/4" Plain Ring (Earlobe) - WHITE GOLD
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#363636;line-height:16px;text-align:center">
                        $110.00
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkY1MTYtZGlhbW9uZC1jb250aW51b3VzLWV0ZXJuaXR5LXJpbmctaGVsaXgtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNldDhkMjItcm9zZS1nb2xkLmh0bWw="
                target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkY1MTYtZGlhbW9uZC1jb250aW51b3VzLWV0ZXJuaXR5LXJpbmctaGVsaXgtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNldDhkMjItcm9zZS1nb2xkLmh0bWw%3D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGemmOPzKqjaMtL6JMsZ5o-WOOWLw"><img class="CToWUd" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/oXpSdsWCQF_bW7AslUS7Fi71WwkcWjSpNklnWUJtDDgaxexkpoqVKaeIWTopPL8YfTZMqfOBV-jW7SV3DOGMi5Eq-o8FhU9JWH69-f-Ukh4dbVTeFoq9yCIuWWGmSwEOA6eaBgkxhzA=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.venusbymariatash.com/media/catalog/product/C/E/CET8D22-ROSE_GOLD_1.png"
                  alt="" style="display:block" border="0" width="210"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#363636;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;text-align:center;padding:0 0 15px">
                5/16" Diamond Continuous Eternity Ring (Helix) - ROSE GOLD
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#363636;line-height:30px;text-align:center">
                $515.00
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="430">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding:20px 0 0">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px" align="center" bgcolor="#fff">
                                <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNyNjUtYi1yb3NlLWdvbGQuaHRtbA==" title="CHECKOUT"
                                style="color:rgb(255,255,255);text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px 50px;background-color:rgb(89,89,89);border-radius:5px" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNyNjUtYi1yb3NlLWdvbGQuaHRtbA%3D%3D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHiQ7uePUKn7qMoF5xqlvjDP1zgyQ"><strong>CHECKOUT</strong></a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding:20px 0 0; min-height: 100px;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px" align="center" bgcolor="#fff">
                                <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtd2hpdGUtZ29sZC1jcjY1LWItd2hpdGUtZ29sZC5odG1s" title="CHECKOUT"
                                style="color:rgb(255,255,255);text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px 50px;background-color:rgb(89,89,89);border-radius:5px" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkYxNC1wbGFpbi1yaW5nLWVhcmxvYmUtd2hpdGUtZ29sZC1jcjY1LWItd2hpdGUtZ29sZC5odG1s&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609004000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFtmdKjjV2n6xrI45EjJ6H9WBAXtA"><strong>CHECKOUT</strong></a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:20px 0 0">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px" align="center" bgcolor="#fff">
                        <a href="https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M=/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkY1MTYtZGlhbW9uZC1jb250aW51b3VzLWV0ZXJuaXR5LXJpbmctaGVsaXgtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNldDhkMjItcm9zZS1nb2xkLmh0bWw="
                        title="CHECKOUT" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px 50px;background-color:rgb(89,89,89);border-radius:5px" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://app.remarkety.com/public/track/link/umk/NTcwNjdkNTdjMWJhMjIuODA4MDE3MzA1NzA2N2Q1N2M%3D/origurl/aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cudmVudXNieW1hcmlhdGFzaC5jb20lMkY1MTYtZGlhbW9uZC1jb250aW51b3VzLWV0ZXJuaXR5LXJpbmctaGVsaXgtcm9zZS1nb2xkLWNldDhkMjItcm9zZS1nb2xkLmh0bWw%3D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1460215609005000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFsZwpDCF5k_yDAE66iSd1Sx1ObnQ"><strong>CHECKOUT</strong></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="15">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using valign="bottom" attribute